# Handling Cortana interpretation mistakes

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I was wondering how to best cope with interpretation mistakes that Cortana sometimes makes.

For instance; I'm building a bot which handles some home automation intents for me using the pre-built home automation entities. Now I've added an intent called HomeAutomation.ActivateScene. This is meant to activate a certain scene set in my home automation software.

Now it's probably my non native accent, but Cortana sometimes doesn't interpret the exact words I speak. This happens mainly to the word 'scene' which she sometimes translates to 'seeing', 'senior' or 'saying' which kinda sound alike.

So now my questions are:

1. Should I take this into account or rely on Cortana improving her listening?
2. If not, I can make sure LUIS gets the right interpretation; but what's the best way? Learn it these other words as part of the intents training? Or somehow learn it to understand sound-a-likes for a certain word?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I had this same problem with Alexa a while back, I added the words Alexa thought I was saying into the utterances so they were mapped to the correct intent to solve the problem.  Probably not the most elegant solution but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try speech recognition priming, which is the process of creating a LUIS app that identifies words that you want your Cortana skill to recognize, and linking it to the Cortana skill. In the LUIS app you would add some representative utterances and label words you want to recognize as entities.

There's an article describing it here: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/26/Speech-To-Text/#intent-based-speech-priming-for-natural-language

Comment: If you are going to provide a link as an answer, provide some context: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# and Dialogs, you could try to play with the parameters of the PromptOptionsWithSynonyms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptoptionswithsynonyms-1.-ctor?view=botbuilder-3.8. If it's just a handful of words that are being misinterpreted, it's a bit of a hack but you could try and add the mistakes as synonyms for "scene". Another option to try is to lower the minScore parameter in PromptDialog.Choice function call (I can't find this in the documentation) but the function is defined as this:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Prompt for one of a set of choices.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   context:
    //     The dialog context.
    //
    //   resume:
    //     Resume handler.
    //
    //   promptOptions:
    //     The prompt options.
    //
    //   recognizeChoices:
    //     (Optional) if true, the prompt will attempt to recognize numbers in the users
    //     utterance as the index of the choice to return. The default value is "true".
    //
    //   recognizeNumbers:
    //     (Optional) if true, the prompt will attempt to recognize ordinals like "the first
    //     one" or "the second one" as the index of the choice to return. The default value
    //     is "true".
    //
    //   recognizeOrdinals:
    //     (Optional) if true, the prompt will attempt to recognize the selected value using
    //     the choices themselves. The default value is "true".
    //
    //   minScore:
    //     (Optional) minimum score from 0.0 - 1.0 needed for a recognized choice to be
    //     considered a match. The default value is "0.4".
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     The type of the options.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     T should implement System.Object.ToString
    public static void Choice<T>(IDialogContext context, ResumeAfter<T> resume, IPromptOptions<T> promptOptions, bool recognizeChoices = true, bool recognizeNumbers = true, bool recognizeOrdinals = true, double minScore = 0.4);
```